# What is the actual practical difference between int x[] and int *x[] in C?

Tags: c, pointers, array-pointer

Although I've learned and worked with many advanced languages, but today when I was refreshing my C skills this old question again striked me. When we talk about pointers in C, simple pointers are easy to undertand, but for me array pointers didn't make sense (as I could never undertand them).

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *y[] = {4, 5, 6};
```

In the above code, if I'll do `printf("%u", x)` it'll give address of first element of x array, which clears the fact that x is a pointer to the array x. Similarly if I'll do `printf("%u", y)` it'll give address of first element of y array.

So what makes x different from y? Can someone please explain.

P.s. I'm not asking about regular pointers, I'm very well verse with the concept of pointers.

Comment: `int *y[] = {4, 5, 6};` is  questionable  code. "warning: initialization of 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]".  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: *if I'll do `printf("%u", x)` it'll give address of first element of x array*  No, it will give you undefined behavior because `x` is not an `unsigned int` so it doesn't match the `%u` format specifier.

Comment: @Shashvat Gupta, `printf("%u", y)` is also UB as `y` does not match `"%u"`.

Comment: @Shashvat Gupta, "I'm very well verse with the concept of pointers." Perhaps, yet it is not demonstrated by this code.

Comment: _"for me array pointers didn't make sense"_ -- Are you interested in `int *y[]`, which is an array of pointers, or in `int (*y)[]`, which is a pointer to an array?

Comment: For `int`, use `%d` (or `%i`).  For `unsigned int`, use `%u` (or `%x` or `%X` or `%o`).  For a pointer (such as `int *`), cast it to `void *`, then use `%p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `int x[] = {1, 2, 3};` defines array of 3 integers
2. `int *y[] = {4, 5, 6}` defines array of 3 ***pointers*** and inializes it with integers **converted** to pointers which basically makes no sense. In such array you want to store references (pointers) to **objects**

```
int a = 4,b = 5,c = 6;
int *y[] = {&a, &b, &c};
```

> In the above code, if I'll do printf("%u", x) it'll give address of
> first element of x array

No, It invokes Undefined behaviour as you use the wrong format specifiers. You need to `printf("%p", (void *)x);`

Comment: I was missing this point. Posted a dumb question, got it voted down, only after that i got clarity. LoL :D
Thanks for the answer anyway (y) .